# Difference between sparsearray and sparsearraycompat

Tags: android, sdk

what is difference between **Sparsearray** and **Sparsearraycompat**.

`Sparsearraycompat` is a copy of the current platform

> (currently  {  @ link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#KITKAT } version of { @link   android.util.SparseArray};

provides a `removeAt()` method and other things.

It's means `Sparsearray` can use everywhere except KITKAT?
why not always use `Sparsearray` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SparseArray` api was changing and improving as newer and newer versions of SDK were released. `SparseArrayCompat` is implementation of `SparseArray` that is distributed trough the support library, so you can use the most fresh api on old SDKs as well.

Comment: Seems that `SparseArrayCompat` is the most recent implementation for older sdks